# Acceptable phone numbers on .net

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I am very new in .net programming. I have a database of product suppliers and there are some details about the suppliers. On the phonetextbox i want the phone number to be at least 8 digits. I coded this but doesn't work. Could you please help me?

```
   'Dim numbers As Decimal = Convert.ToDecimal(PhoneTextBox.Text)
    Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("^\d{8}")
    Dim match As Match = regex.Match(numbers)
    If Not match.Success() Then
        MessageBox.Show("Attention!!!The phone number must be at least 8 digits")
        e.Cancel = True
    End If

End Sub`
```

Comment: a phone number is not a decimal, if you want to save it formatted, it is not even a numeric type.  no need for Regex just to test the length: PhoneTextBox.Text.Length

Comment: Please read [ask] and show how exactly this "doesn't work".

Comment: Also, no need to alarm the user with lots of exclamation points!!!! It was just a typo!!!!  A status bar message or `ErrorProvider` would be less annoying that a MessageBox that has to be dismissed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should pretty much accomplish what you're trying to do. As said in comments, no need for regex for a length check and it should definitely be a string and NOT a numeric type.

```
    Dim submission = "1234567"
    If (submission.Length <= 8 ) Then
        Console.WriteLine("Attention!!!The phone number must be at least 8 digits")
    'e.Cancel = True
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Sub Main()
        Dim phonePattern As New Regex("^\d{3}-\d{7}$")
        Dim phoneNumber As String = "210-1234567"

        If (Not phonePattern.IsMatch(phoneNumber)) Then
            Console.WriteLine("Number {0} is not in right format [999-9999999]", phoneNumber)
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Number {0} is in right format [999-9999999]", phoneNumber)
        End If


        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
```